# Where can I find Google Cloud Account: Email ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-cloud-storage

One of my clients has a WordPress site. He has stored his "Media content" (i.e. images) in Google Cloud Storage by using the WP-Stateless plugin. While trying to retrieve it, the client didn't know what Email Id was used? We have Google a Cloud Storage service-account.json only.

This is the image URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/stateless-frontstreetbabies-com/2018/10/e58e63bf-logo-front-street-baby.png

1. How to find the email account associated with the above Google Storage image in the Google Cloud console?
2. If we couldn't find an email account, then how to get that information previously stored in Google Cloud?
3. If we change to our Google Storage account, how to retrieve the previously stored files and media in our Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Have you tried [the documentation of the plugin](https://wp-stateless.github.io/docs/manual-setup/)?

Answer (score 1):

> How to find email account associated with the above Google Storage
>   image in the Google Cloud console?

Unless you already know this you cannot. Your error message does have the Google Cloud Project Number. You can provide this to [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing).

> If we couldn't find email account, then how to get that information
>   previously stored in Google Cloud?

You cannot. To access information for a Google Cloud Platform account requires authorization. Since your problem is a billing problem, you will need to contact Google and resolve that first.

> If we change to our Google Storage account, how to retrieve the
>   previously stored files and media in our Google Cloud Storage?

Same answer. Until you resolve the billing problem you are frozen.

Remember, you only have 30 days from the start of the billing problem. After that date, everything is deleted.